# Can't select in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE LikesBabble (
    user VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    babble SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    type CHAR(7) CHECK (type IN ('like','dislike')),
    created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (user, babble),
    FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES BabbleUser(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (babble) REFERENCES Babble(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

the BabbleUser and Babble tables are simple tables to store user's data and "babbles" (something like a Twitter copycat)

When I try to "select * from likesbabble" it doesn't return anything if I add "where user = 'student_1'" even though the table has a user with that name.

if I try to select by babble [which is the id] or anything else it works.

if I try "where user like '%'" it works but "where user like '%e%'" it doesn't.

what is going on, and why can't I select anything from the user col?

Comment: Does LEttEr CAse MatteR? I.e. should it be STUDENT_1 instead of student_1?

Comment: it doesn't with the BabbleUser table, I tried all upper case, all lower case, and tried exactly like it is written in the table, nothing works.

Comment: I might need to add that I can select users from the BabbleUser table, and I was able to select from this one by inner joining it with the BabbleUser then selecting according to that one, but then I can't user delete, update etc. which i need :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `USER` is a function that returns current name. Try with `"`:

```
SELECT *
FROM LikesBabble
WHERE "user" LIKE '%e%';
```

Also using keyword/reserved words is not best idea. More at: [Reserved words](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_reservedwords.html);

---

Demo from SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE a ("USER" VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('Jones');

SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE user LIKE 'Jones';

SELECT user
FROM a;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GJRIU2857)**

I guess it is similliar case.

Comment: didn't work, but probably it is because it is a reserved word :|

I just trusted that because our lovely university has set up the tables for us, well it is not like it is there first mess up....

Comment: changed the col name from user to useraname and now it works lol.
I guess it is because of the reserved words. thanks a lot!